# pyinstaller importError: No module name '_socket'

Tags: python, sockets, pyinstaller

I am using:

- pyinstaller 3.2 (I also try development version)
- Windows 10
- python 3.5.2

The code is:

```
import socket

print("test")
so = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
so.setblocking(True)  
print(so)
```

I launch pyinstaller like this

```
pyinstaller --noupx -D --log-level DEBUG test.py
```

And when I launch the executable i get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "socket.py", line 49, in <module>
ImportError: No module named '_socket'
Failed to execute script test
```

The warning file warntest.txt look like this (I have shortened it)

```
[...]
missing module named math.cos - imported by math, random, D:\Projet\eq_sim\test.py
missing module named socket.SOCK_STREAM - imported by socket, ssl, D:\Projet\eq_sim\test.py
missing module named socket.AF_INET - imported by socket, ssl, D:\Projet\eq_sim\test.py
missing module named socket.SO_TYPE - imported by socket, ssl, D:\Projet\eq_sim\test.py
missing module named socket.SOL_SOCKET - imported by socket, ssl, D:\Projet\eq_sim\test.py
missing module named copy.deepcopy - imported by copy, weakref, email.generator, D:\Projet\eq_sim\test.py
[...]
```

I have check the page https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/If-Things-Go-Wrong to find out my issue but no success.

I have check the archive file
**out00-PYZ.pyz**, it seems ok

In the  directory [...]bincache00_py35_32bit/ the file **_socket.pyd** is present so it seems to find it.

I have tried adding paths (-p) and others stuff, the result is always the same

It is a pretty simple case, so I think I am missing something here

Comment: I could not reproduce this problem in similar environment.

Comment: thank for your comment, so the issue come from my environment, I will try on another machine, and change python3 installation form "all user" to "user only"

Answer (score 8):

Ok guys... I am ashamed ... I was not running the good executable file.

I was running the exe file in the **build/** directory, I had to run the one in the **dist/** directory.

Comment: please mark your answer as ANSWERED. it really save my day :D

Comment: PLEASE, mark as answered.... This also saved my day. I mean, night :D